Little league baseball 10 yr and under
Batter hits ball.  First baseman bobbles ball but catches with bare hand and tags first base with glove (ball remains in bare hand).
Is the runner out or safe?

To clarify- part of the fielder’s body was touching first base, while in a hand they had full control of the ball, all before the batter touched first base. Correct? If so, batter is out in baseball generally.  You state an age and little league and we have no way of knowing if the league has some modified “house rules”. Also, did you mean “bare” hand?

Under MLB rules, this is an out.
"Tag" is defined as:

A TAG is the action of a fielder in touching a base with his body
while holding the ball securely and firmly in his hand or glove; or
touching a runner with the ball, or with his hand or glove holding the
ball (not including hanging laces alone), while holding the ball securely
and firmly in his hand or glove.

So the first baseman, after bobbling at first, is holding the ball securely and firmly in their hand (specifically their non-glove hand), and touches the base with their body (specifically their glove hand).  And the glove, like any other part of the player's equipment when properly worn, counts as part of their body.  Thus they have successfully tagged first base and the batter-runner is out.

Using Little League Rules (p. 127), a "tag" is defined very similarly to the MLB definition:

A TAG is the action of a fielder in touching a base with the body
while holding the ball securely and firmly in the hand or glove; or
touching a runner with the ball, or with the hand or glove holding the
ball, while holding the ball securely and firmly in the hand or glove.

Emphasis above addresses the scenario described in the question.
